# Camunda/Activity Service Tasks

Tags: java, workflow-activity, camunda

We are modelling processes with bpm and executing said bpm with the camunda engine in a Spring environment. In one scenario I'd like to execute custom Java code in between two user tasks. My conclusion from reading much of the camunda documentation is, that I'm best off with the Service-Task concept.

I'd like to do two things, one is to store more than one process-variable with the service task and two is to dynamically define, which process variables map to which input parameter of the Service-Task

To my knowledge Camunda offers two ways of integrating Java Code with service tasks:

1.) Declare a Spring-Bean implementing the JavaDelegate interface. (The method gets a DelegateExecution as parameter). This one would allow me to store as many result-variables as I like but I see no option of defining a mapping process-variable -> input-variable.

2.) Declare a generic Spring bean to be accessible by camunda and define the method of that bean to be executed by the system task. This allows me top specify the process-variable -> input-variable pattern via bpm-definition but stores at most one result-variable.

So, is there a way to achieve both?

**Clarification**

To clarify my requirements, on occasion my system-tasks might detect an inconsistent state (in database or process variables). I would like the tasks to store an error-code (similar to error codes of programs "exit(1)") in the process variables so that following user tasks get the chance to correct the error. This error-code might as well be stored in a fixed location in the process variables, however I want to be able to put at least one "real result" in a designated location.

Comment: Not quite sure what you would like to achive.
Do you want create/update multiple process variables from within a service task implementation?
And where should the input mapping come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to implement the behavior in a Spring bean that uses the current execution to read and update the variables.

You would wire the spring bean named `myErrorHandler` with a service task like this

```
<serviceTask id="checkError"
             camunda:expression="#{myErrorHandler.checkError(execution)}" />
```

The `execution` variable is available in the expression per default and points to an instance of [DelegateExecution](http://docs.camunda.org/latest/api-references/javadoc/?org/camunda/bpm/engine/delegate/DelegateExecution.html) that gives you access to the current process variables.

The implementation of the Spring bean may look as follows:

```
@Component
public class MyErrorHandler {

  /**
   * Actual error handler invoked as service
   */
  public void checkError(DelegateExecution execution) {

    execution.getVariables(); // Map<String, Object> of variables

    execution.setVariable("errorCode", 500); // update variable
  }
}
```

Comment: So "execution" is a default variable which is always present in the ProcessVariables?

Comment: Just checked: Yes, it is. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, it is available per default. I updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Is there an overview over the implicit variavbles available to systemtasks? I've found out, that it is not only a `DelegateExecution` but actually an `ActivityExecution` (which is much more useful) and I would like to know whether this is a lucky accident or by design.

Comment: Check out the [service task documentation](http://docs.camunda.org/latest/api-references/bpmn20/#tasks-service-task) for all the options. The interface the engine exposes is indeed `DelegateExecution`. You should use it unless you know what you are doing.